# How sqoop mappers split data into blocks when the default value is 4?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I know that the default value of **Sqoop** mappers is 4 and we can change that value. But because the data is being saved in HDFS during a Sqoop import, say my block size is *128 MB* and the total size of the data is **3 GB**. This means my data is going to to split into 24 parts excluding the replication across all the datanodes. My question is that if I use 4 sqoop mappers, then how does it is split into 24 parts? Does each mapper internally splits the data into 6 parts? What exactly happens here? I am confused! Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer after a long time. The answer is simple. It is independent of the fact that in how many parts the data is stored in HDFS. So even if I used 4(default) mappers during Sqoop and the data is saved in 4 parts, when I try to use any MapReduce Job with say 10 mappers, the 4 data files distribute the data among 10 mappers. All these are higher level stuffs and and an user don't need to bother about it.